# I'm getting this npm start error . React js vs code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, nvm

Please help me guys . I completed all my coding part . At the end while trying npm start I'm getting errors

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\yateesh\Downloads\grpchat/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\yateesh\Downloads\grpchat\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yateesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-01T07_25_04_450Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\yateesh\Downloads\grpchat>

Comment: Check the `package.json` file is exist at project path.

Comment: share your project's directory structure

Answer (score 0):

It seems your package.json is missing.